# Batch file - Discovered resolution

Tags: batch-file, screen-resolution

I'm trying to figure out a method of detecting if a users resolution is higher or lower than "1280 x 1024" through a batch file.

If the resolution is "1280 x 1024" or higher then do A. Otherwise do B.

Does anyone have any idea how this could be done?

Cheers,

Elliott

Comment: this post seems similar with [this post][1] ^_^


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/270718/get-display-resolution-from-windows-command-line

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to registry, you can also check resolution via `Wmic`:
`wmic desktopmonitor where availability=3 get screenHeight,screenWidth`
More on the **Win32_DesktopMonitor** class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Be wary that it's possible to get multiple lines if there is more than 1 monitor attached - you should handle those cases in your script.

Comment: Hm, stupid me. WMI should have been the obvious answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky for several reasons:

1. The resolution is in the registry, you can query that with `reg.exe`. However, it's not really easy to find. For me it's under

   ```
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{7FD4F64D-A7B2-41A9-AEEB-835BE4473FFA}\0000
   ```

   in `DefaultSettings.XResolution` and `DefaultSettings.YResolution`. However, the GUID likely varies depending on what video card and driver you have, so you'd have to iterate all under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video`.
2. What do you mean with a higher resolution? Would 1366 × 768 be higher than 1280 × 1024? Do you count total pixel count? Higher in one dimension? In both?

In any case, I cobbled together the following batch. Adapt if necessary. It produces the correct result on my machine, but I don't have that many to test on.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%l in ('reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video') do (
    reg query %%l\0000 /v DefaultSettings.XResolution >nul 2>&1
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%x in ('reg query %%l\0000 /v DefaultSettings.XResolution') do (
            set /a X=%%x
        )
        for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%x in ('reg query %%l\0000 /v DefaultSettings.YResolution') do (
            set /a Y=%%x
        )
    )
)
echo Resolution: %X% × %Y%

if %X% GTR 1280 if %Y% GTR 1024 echo Greater than 1280 × 1024.
```

Comment: I think I'd say if either value was lower than what I've stated then B should be executed.

Comment: Elliot, see my edit; you should be able to adapt it from there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `wmic desktopmonitor` returns nothing.

This one works for me on Win 8.1

```
@ECHO OFF

for /f "delims=" %%# in  ('"wmic path Win32_VideoController  get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution /format:value"') do (
  set "%%#">nul
)

echo %CurrentHorizontalResolution%
echo %CurrentVerticalResolution%
```